# Scala Spark Streaming job with spark-submit gets RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM error

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

I am running a spark streaming job using `spark-submit` on an EMR node in AWS. This streams from kafka topic and outputs to another kafka topic. The job is written in **scala.**

I execute the job like this:

```
spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--num-executors 2 \
--total-executor-cores 1 \
--executor-cores 1 \
--executor-memory 1g \
--driver-memory 1g \
--name my-spark-job \
--class com.example.Main \
--queue default \
--conf "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true" \
--conf "spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true" \
--conf "spark.driver.memoryOverhead=1024m" \
--conf "spark.executor.memoryOverhead=1024m" \
--deploy-mode cluster 
spark-job-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I see in logs that the job is sent to yarn and it gets this **ERROR SIGNAL TERM**:

```
20/05/06 10:41:04 INFO spark.ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 181
20/05/06 10:41:09 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
20/05/06 10:41:09 INFO streaming.StreamingContext: Invoking stop(stopGracefully=false) from shutdown hook
20/05/06 10:41:09 INFO scheduler.ReceiverTracker: ReceiverTracker stopped
20/05/06 10:41:09 INFO scheduler.JobGenerator: Stopping JobGenerator immediately
20/05/06 10:41:09 INFO util.RecurringTimer: Stopped timer for JobGenerator after time 1588761660000
20/05/06 10:41:09 INFO scheduler.JobGenerator: Stopped JobGenerator
20/05/06 10:41:09 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Stopped JobScheduler
20/05/06 10:41:09 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3fa68e57{/streaming,null,UNAVAILABLE,@Spark}
20/05/06 10:41:09 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@446023a8{/streaming/batch,null,UNAVAILABLE,@Spark}
20/05/06 10:41:09 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4e16f11a{/static/streaming,null,UNAVAILABLE,@Spark}
20/05/06 10:41:09 INFO streaming.StreamingContext: StreamingContext stopped successfully
20/05/06 10:41:09 INFO spark.SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
20/05/06 10:41:09 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: SUCCEEDED, exitCode: 0
20/05/06 10:41:09 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Stopped Spark@5bec9336{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:0}

.....
... further down i get ...
...
20/05/06 10:41:00 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 7
20/05/06 10:41:00 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 6
20/05/06 10:41:09 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
20/05/06 10:41:09 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Shutdown hook called
20/05/06 10:41:09 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

Is there something I need to set in the config or anything else I may be missing? Would appreciate any hints here, thanks!

Comment: I think these are driver logs , were you able to also check the executor logs for any OOMs

Comment: Where would I find executor logs? I get logs from EMR node by running command: `yarn logs -applicationId <application_id>`

Comment: Try looking at In the S3 location look at `task-attempts/<applicationid>/<firstcontainer>/`

Comment: Can you post executor logs .. if no errors means someone might have killed using yarn kill or from spark ui..

Comment: S3 bucket is empty in AWS. I'm gonna try finding it on hadoop master with command but no luck yet: `hdfs dfs -ls -R /`